# Query about working with git and VS2010 as window user

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Recently github has launched [client for window user](http://windows.github.com/) and i have installed in my system and  it's very easy to clone, commit and push changes with local and remote repository. this client is working on http instead of ssh path.

Before this i was using Git Extension according to [this link](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/05/06/git-ssh-putty-github-unfuddle-the-kitchen-sink.aspx) i have set up in my system and it's worked well with Visual studio as well as from directory and it was totally based on ssh.

Now my problem is that i have installed new client and it will not going to use SSH anyway so is there any extension to work with visual studio that can sync with repository according to this new github's client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not matter. You can have multiple remotes set up for the same repository. I would advise on using git from the command line anyway. Visual Studio integration is overrated. You give up a lot of functionality if you are not using the command line:

- searchable history
- command chaining
- tab completion